# ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND infinitely on startup

Tags: arch-linux, acpi

I just did a system update and upgrade on my Arch desktop. Just after getting past GRUB, I get this scrolling on the screen forever: [image: this]

```
ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F]...
ACPI Error: [PGRT]_Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND...
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F]...
```

What's going on? I found http://jhshi.me/2015/11/14/acpi-error-method-parseexecution-failed-_gpe_l6f/index.html and tried to implement it from my LiveUSB, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this [guide](http://jhshi.me/2015/11/14/acpi-error-method-parseexecution-failed-_gpe_l6f/index.html). I was able to boot turning off [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) by adding the `acpi=off` flag in grub.

Then I followed the guide above and was able to boot **without** `acpi=off`:

1. If using sysdemd with rc.local disabled:

   ```
   systemctl enable rc-local.service
   ```
2. Edit

   ```
   sudo systemctl edit --full rc-local
   ```
3. Add to rc.local

   ```
   echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F
   ```

There were still a few of the ACPI error messages, but they did not affect booting.